# Python simple base to base converter returns nothing as result

Tags: python, input, integer, hex, bin

I am trying to make a basic base to base converter. Basically the user enters a number, then enters the base he needs the number converted to, and the program converts the number. For example I enter `Number? 0x10C`, `Base wanted? 10` and the program returns the result as `268`.

Here is my code:

```
toConvertBase = int(input("Base wanted? "))
if toConvertBase=="10":
    result=int(numberToConvert)
    print(result)
elif toConvertBase=="2":
    result=bin(numberToConvert)
    print(result)
elif toConvertBase=="16":
    result=hex(numberToConvert)
    print(result)
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here, but the program shows nothing as result:

```
Enter a number? 0xCAFE
Base wanted? 10
```

Please help :)

Comment: `toConvertBase` is `10`, not `'10'`...

Comment: No ``int``eger can ever equal *the string* ``"10"``, ``"2"`` or ``"16"``.

Answer (score 1):

You are converting your `input` to `int`, and then checking if it's a sting.

```
toConvertBase = input("Base wanted? ")
if toConvertBase=="10":
    result=int(numberToConvert)
    print(result)
elif toConvertBase=="2":
    result=bin(numberToConvert)
    print(result)
elif toConvertBase=="16":
    result=hex(numberToConvert)
    print(result)
```